# Decomposing a weakly chordal graph into disjoint union of co-chordal graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph G is said to be co-chordal if it is $\bar C_n$-free for any $n \ge 4$. It is weakly chordal if it is $C_n$ and $\bar C_n$ free for all $n\ge 5$. Assume that the induced matching number of $G$ is $2$. By a theorem of Busch, Dragan and Sritharan we know that there exist two co-chordal graphs $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $G = H_1 \cup H_2$. Also, there exist co-pairs $e$ and $f$ that form a $2K_2$. We may assume that $e\in H_1$ and $f\in H_2$. Note that $G-e$ is weakly chordal and has induced matching number at most $2$. I'm wondering if there exists a such a decomposition where:

1. $H_1$ and $H_2$ are edge disjoint.
2. $H_1-e$ is also co-chordal.

In other words, $H_1 -e \cup H_2$ is a decomposition for $G-e$.

Comment: What does $\bar C_n$-free mean?

Comment: $\bar C_n$ means complement of a cycle of length $n$. $\bar C_n$-free means no induced subgraph of $G$ is isomorphic to $\bar C_n$ for some $n$.